# How to configure the DNS with Azure Web Application

Tags: azure, web-applications, dns

Am working on the **Azure Web Application** and **Azure DNS**.Here I don't have any Custom Domains like **GODADDY** etc. am just using Azure DNS only.Now, am trying to call my Web Application in the name of my DNS name. For that, I created records like CNAME,TXT,* in the DNS on the Web Application and when am trying to validate them in the Web Application **Custom Domain** template. It’s not validating **Domain Ownership** and showing error as shown in figure:

[image]

For this I followed the Microsoft [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain). Can you suggest me “How to overcome this issue?”

Comment: Could you add the DNS records you added to the question? If you want to keep the domain secret, you can just replace it with e.g. `domain.com`.

Comment: Yes, I added the DNS records and for keeping my domain secret , I used the name as "webapp.com"

Comment: I don't see the records in your question. Did you edit them in the question? If not could you add them? It is hard to say if there is something wrong with them if we cannot see them :D

Comment: Now, You can see it

Comment: Okay, I can see what it requires, though I cannot see if you set them like that. If you go to http://digwebinterface.com and enter your domain in the search + select TXT, do you get the expected value? Try the same for the A record.

Comment: Yeah, am getting CNAME and its IP-address which I have assigned, When am trying it as domain TXT in search in digwebinterface.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177020/discussion-between-mani-and-juunas).

Comment: If the issue has been resolved, you can post the solution as an answer and it will help others.